# External data source to Vespa

Tags: vespa

I am working on a master thesis where I am at the moment trying to research the state-of-the-art of stream processing, and big data management systems which support real-time analysis, all in one system. I wonder if Vespa provide functionality for connecting the engine to external data sources, then let this data flow into the document processor, before the data is stored?

To be more precise, an issue of many approaches today is that for instance streaming engines and persistent stores must be combined. So, does Vespa have native support for feed ingestion, from external data sources?

Answer (score 1):

Vespa obviously provides api's for operating on data (CRUD + Visit/stream) but we don't have native persistence engine/database connectors.